# Access Denied: Table : Permission bigquery.tables.get denied on table X

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been given the role of BigQuery user. After being assigned, I am able to view tables and execute queries on them, but after a few minutes, I am getting

```
Access Denied: Table : Permission bigquery.tables.get denied on table X
```

My role still stays the same, but I can't access the tables now. We tried it a few times, but the result is the same. How can we solve it?

Comment: is table X the table or a view? if it is a view then you might not have permission to access one or more of its dependencies

Comment: Hi @Tugay, Have you assigned the appropriate role of [BigQuery user](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.user) or the role of BigQuery [Data Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/knowledge/kb/access-denied-unauthorized-errors-on-a-bigquery-view-000004325#solution) to the service account that you are using ?

Comment: @DhirajSingh I had been assinged Data Viewer first - in this case I wasn't able to execute queries, but i could see table previews etc and it didn't change. Then I was assigned BigQuery User role and I could only see previews and stuff for a few minutes, then it gave me the error I have shared on the post

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.